# HTTPrequest using axios results in CORS error

Tags: node.js, cors, axios

I build my own API which is running on port 5000. Whenever I want to make a request to it , I get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/user' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I already did some research but the only thing that seems to work is a chrome extension, which isnt ideal.

```
Here's what i did : 

    const config = {
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, browsers block responses if server does not allow CORS. So if you are using NodeJS at your API, use this [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).